# apache virtual host, second alias not work

Tags: apache, virtualhost

i will create some alias in my apache virtual host, but the only first alias work fine, what i mistake?

```
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/Ext6Workspace/MyApp

    #alias per prelevare extjs da locale
    Alias "/extlib" "C:/wamp/www/Ext6Workspace/ext/build"
    Alias "/MyApp" "/app"
```

if i call **http://myapp.localhost/MyApp/view/main/Main.js** the browser respond with 404, but if i replace "MyApp" in url with "app" work.
if i try call some file with http://myapp.localhost/extlib, all work fine.

Comment: http://myapp.localhost/MyApp/view/main/Main.js = 404 HTTPCODE
http://myapp.localhost/app/view/main/Main.js = 200 HTTPCODE
http://myapp.localhost/extlib/athers.js = 200 HTTPCODE

Comment: also, rewrite not work(in tester work fine http://htaccess.mwl.be/)
#++++++++++++++++++++
  #alias per prelevare extjs da locale
  Alias "/extlib" "C:/wamp/www/Ext6Workspace/ext/build"

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^GhilbliApp app [L]
  #+++++++++++++++++++++